# Solve an inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

How do I solve this inequality for x?
How can I solve for x in these kinds of equations in general?

$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right| < \varepsilon$$

Comment: You DO denote Euler's constant by $e$, right?

Comment: No, e is a number bigger than 0

Comment: e is not the best choice to indicate a generic number!

Comment: Sorry, I tried epsilon but I don't have it on my keyboard

Comment: Write `$\varepsilon$` for $\varepsilon$.

Comment: You want to find $x$ such that this inequality is true for all $\varepsilon>0$? Or to find the function $x(\varepsilon)$?

Comment: Note that if you're working with epsilon-delta, you usually don't need an exact solution.  All you need is $x$ to be small enough for the inequality to hold.

Comment: @Holo He wants *all* $x$.

Comment: No.given an epsilon find all x that satisfy this inequality.  I'm not working with epsilon delta.

Comment: BTW thanks for everyone that helped\is helping

Comment: user532929, given @gimusi 's and my answer, the only way to do it exact is when you have your variable $>=1$, else it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can't do it exactly.

I will set the absolute values aside. We will soon see why they don't really matter for your question. It would just be a per case distinction to solve $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}<\varepsilon$ and $\frac{-\sin(x)}{x}<\varepsilon$ anyway. Also for the moment let's consider equality rather than inequality because the equal case is the border case for the inequality solutions and usually helps finding them very much.

We have $\sin(x)$ = $\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$, we need to solve
$$\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right) = x\varepsilon$$
Behind this lies the problem of solving equations like $z=ae^z$, but we can't do this exactly. There is something called the [Lambert W-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) $W$ which gives us the (or better: a) inverse for the function $f(z)=ze^z$. $W$ cannot be expressed in "basic" mathematical terms, we can't write it down with finite terms, not even as something complicated like $e^{\sin(\log z)}z^{\frac{1}{z}}$. We can only get its values numerically. So, we can express the solutions of $ae^z$ in terms of the $W$ Function, it would be $-W(-a)$ ([found here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20z%3Dae%5Ez), assuming $a\neq 0$). If there is any way to solve $\sin(x)=x\varepsilon$, it would probably like that. Wolfram Alpha doesn't have enough calculation power to do that for me, but it gives a nice graph over the solution space, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Da*sin(x)).

See also [Roots of $f(x)=\sin(x)-ax$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606106/roots-of-fx-sinx-ax)

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect, I just want to point out that we can find the power series for the Lambert W-function: $$W(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}z^n$$

Comment: @Holo Hm. I always somehow thought "not expressable in elementary functions" includes power series. Where does it converge?

Comment: I never said you are wrong, I just think it can be helpful. and what do you mean "where does it converges?"?

Comment: @Holo I'm wondering where the power series of the Lambert W-function converges i.e. what the convergence radius is. Probably easy to calculate, but I can't remember right now how to do it. That aside, now I'm a bit confused. "Expressable in elementary functions" only means as finite concatenations of basic operations (including $e$ and $\log$), right?

Comment: using the ratio test I got $\frac1e$ for the radius of converges. and you are right about elementary functions, I mean that even if it is not elementary it may help. You weren't wrong, I just thought it is information that is worth mentioning

Comment: @Holo It clearly is, but I'm removing the integral from my example of a "basic yet complicated" example, so the example becomes an elementary function.

Comment: The answer does not address the question, which is about an inequality. It also drops the case of $\sin x=-\epsilon x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust To get the set of all numbers that fulfill the inequality, I replace $<$ by $=$ and look for solutions, afterwards I take my solutions as bounds for the solution space of the inequality. If you know any other way to do this besides direct manipulation (what is not possible in this case), please tell me, I'm eager to learn. Also it is kind of unfair to say that I "drop a case". I clearly stated that it is just a "per case distinction" and in no way relevant in comparison to the real problem at hand. A per cases solution doesn't help if all solutions are "not exactly possible".

Comment: @SK19: this belongs to the answer, not just a comment. You also skip the discussion of where the equation has real roots.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Luckily there is an edit button. And what real roots am I missing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|<1$$

thus the inequality

$$\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|<k$$

is always true $\forall x \neq 0$ when $k\ge 1$.

Otherwise we can have 2 or more solution depending on the value of k.

[Plot of $\sin x/x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Csinx%2Fx%7C)

Comment: I know that, but I want to find x, not how many xs exist that satisfy this inequality. (x = f(k))

Comment: The only simple way is to find the maximum of $|\sin x/x|$

Answer (score 0):

The equation associated to the inequation cannot be solved analytically an requires numerical methods. Anyway, you cannot dispense yourself of root isolation.

From the plot of $|\text{sinc } x|$, it is obvious that there are two roots per interval $[k\pi,(k+1)\pi]$ where the maximum reaches $\epsilon$. The maxima are realized at the roots of the derivative, which are solutions of

$$x=\tan x,$$ also to be found numerically. They are $0$, and numbers closer and closer to the vertical asymptotes of the tangent function, at $\dfrac{k\pi}2$.

Let $x_k$ be the locations of these maxima. Then for all $k$ such that
$$\left|\dfrac {\sin x_k}{x_k}\right|>\epsilon,$$ we have two  roots at some $x'_k$ and $x''_k$, comprised between successive multiples of $\pi$.

Then the solution of the inequation is made of open intervals $(x'_k,x''_k)$, and with $K$ being the last $k$ for which the equation has a solution, $[x'_K,\infty)$ and symmetrically in the negatives.

Finally, note that when $\epsilon>1$, the largest maximum is exceeded and the solution set is $\mathbb R$.